# Trying to rotate an image according to the angle of the device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-motion

I am trying to rotate an image based on the angle the device is at however when I implement my code nothing happens to the image. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
```

import CoreMotion

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let manager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01

        if manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {

            manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue) {
                [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                    if let gravity = data?.gravity {
                        let rotation = atan2(gravity.x, gravity.y) - M_PI
                        self?.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotation))

                    }
            }
        }
        manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }
}
```

The problem is the `if let data = manager.deviceMotion` never runs. I am not getting any errors and am wondering what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does "rotate according to" mean? Do you mean the image should always appear to be upright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by calling `manager.startGyroUpdates()` instead of `manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()`

Answer (score 2):

To quote the documentation on the motion manager:

> **Device motion**. Call the `startDeviceMotionUpdates(using:)` or `startDeviceMotionUpdates()` method to begin updates and periodically
>   access CMDeviceMotion objects by reading the deviceMotion property.
>   The `startDeviceMotionUpdates(using:)` method (new in iOS 5.0) lets you
>   specify a reference frame to be used for the attitude estimates.

You need to start motion updates before the `deviceMotion` property will be valid.

### EDIT:

Regarding the new code you posted:

Have you stepped through the code to see what happens? Does `manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable` evaluate to true? Is your block being called?

Note that you're passing an `OperationQueue` to your call to `manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates`, so the block you pass in will be invoked on a background thread. You therefore need to send UI updates to the main thread:

```
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue) {
  [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
  if let gravity = data?.gravity {
    let rotation = atan2(gravity.x, gravity.y) - M_PI
    //Change the image view's transform from the main thread.
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
      self?.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotation))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code in the original but I still get the same result. (Apologies, couldn't get the formatting right)

Comment: The `manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable` does evaluate to true however it seems that anything after `manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue) ` does not run.

Comment: I fixed it by calling `manager.startGyroUpdates()`. Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: I answered my own question but if you put the answer in your answer then I will make your answer the correct one since you helped me.